# CentOs fstab mounted cifs folder is empty

Tags: centos, cifs, fstab

I have a folder on my nas mounted in my fstab:

```
//192.168.1.4/datarr /mnt/datarr cifs username=plex,pass=mypw,uid=1000,gid=999,nobrl 0 0
```

This was working fine before. Verified in terminal and also because I run plex on the vm and it was working fine using those folders.

Now when I start the machine the folder appears empty if I

```
cd /mnt/datarr
```

then it's empty. But another VM on the network also has it mounted and it's fine. Furthermore if I open a file browser in this centos machine and browse to 192.168.1.4 and double click on the datarr folder I can see the contents just fine!

Why does the folder appear empty in the shell but the file browser, other clients etc can see it just fine?!

Comment: Can you run the mount command on your client to see if the drive got actually mounted properly? If not, try mounting it manually and check the error messages you get....